Failed to open the explicit specified database
When our application tries to connect to the Availability Group Database, we get the following error message on the primary replica:
Login failed for user 'xxx'. Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database 'abc' [CLIENT:...] ...Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 38
where xxx is the service account running the SQL service.
I have tried using the listener name and cluster name in the connection string. I have tried including the port number (1433). Any ideas whatelse I can try please?
Please note that this is not a stacked SQL instance deployment, only one instance with one AG.
Thank you

That error means that either the user doesn't have access to the database, or the database doesn't exist.
It's ambiguous because if a user doesn't have access to a database, the user also can't discover whether that database exists.
SQL Server has Metadata Security: "The visibility of metadata is limited to securables that a user either owns or on which the user has been granted some permission.".

thank you for your response. It turned out that there was a firewall block from the application server to the database server. The issue is now resolved. Thanks again.
